# How to migrate agent job permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances

When migrating sql server I use this script to migrate logins and server role membership.

Users are complaining unable to access the sql agent jobs. How to migrate the agent job permissions? Does this need me to script the msdb permissions separately?

Comment: Check the users membership in appropriate SQLAgent roles in the source msdb database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles

Comment: Is there a way to script this?

Comment: try the following:   exec sp_helprolemember